# Как начать массив с единицы - PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Есть вот такой массив:

```
    array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(154)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(157)
  }
}
```

Как сделать, чтоб массив начинался с единицы? Вот так:

```
 array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(154)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["variant_id"]=>
    int(157)
  }
}
```

Если придется использовать цикл, то желательно через `foreach`, буду благодарен за ваши ответы.

Comment: Вы уверены что это вам нужно ? Могу предположить что если вы хотите изменить порядок в массиве который начинается с единицы, то у вас что то пошло не так.  Поймите - любые действия с массивом далее (будь то фильтрация, сортировка и т.п.)  не дают вам гарантии сохранения очередности (или очередности ключей). Вы же не собираетесь всегда после всех действий над данными менять последовательность с  нуля на единицу в ключах массива ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = [0,1,2,3];
array_unshift($a, NULL);
unset($a[0]);

var_dump($a);
```